# my kotlin class is not seeing the xml file

Tags: xml, layout, binding, android-viewholder

```
this is my xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/like_this"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
this is my kotlin class

package com.example.todo.example.todolist

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todo.R
import res.xml

 
class TodoAdapter (
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>
) :RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>(){
     class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) :RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
         return TodoViewHolder(
             LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                 R.layout.item_todo,
                 parent,
                 false
             )
         )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
      val curTodo= todos[position]
      holder.itemView.apply {
          tVTodoTitle.text= curTodo.title
          cbDone.isChecked=curTodo.isChecked

      }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return todos.size
    }
}
```

when trying to write tvTitleTodo or cbDone in kotlin class it gives an error and is unable to see the tvTitleTodo and cbDone in the xml file,and I can't tell what is wrong with my code or should i try importing the xml file?I'm talking about the onBindViewHolder part. please someone help